# IIS URL Rewrite - include title in URL based on ID

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have an ASP.NET e-commerce application in which product URLs are primarily of the format

```
<domain_name>/ProductCatalog/Product.aspx?ID=30
```

I am using IIS URL Rewrite to successfully write this URL as

```
<domain_name>/ProductCatalog/Product/30
```

Let's say the product name is "XYZ Item" for `ID = 30` in the database, then I would like to do the lookup and rewrite the URL as

```
<domain_name>/ProductCatalog/Product/XYZ-Item
```

I am not sure how to go about this?  Please point me in the correct direction.